# generate script that will create db schema

Tags: xml, database, schema, pojo

*How do I generate script that will create database schema from xml or pojo. Doing a crud operations spring boot, it is going to execute a script on db*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should try to code this for yourself (otherwise how should you learn if you just copy-paste the solution). Then you can show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where the problem is and ask for some help. Otherwise how would you learn something?

Comment: im asking when we do crud operations on spring boot for example create operation this go to db and execute script that going to create update etc. How could i generate this script ?

Answer (score 0):

i was asking
these properties to get script for ddl
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql